# Can I travel from a tier 4 area in the UK to the Netherlands under current restrictions?

Tags: united-kingdom, netherlands

I am part way through moving from the UK to the Netherlands and now caught up in a catch-22 situation. I have got my residency in NL approved, and have done the biometric testing, but I am in the UK now and need to be in NL to have my residency permit delivered to my current house there. I know that I have to have a PCR test to get into the country but I can find very little information on being allowed to leave the UK from tier 4. I can only see "work reasons" on the Gov UK site. Is being a Dutch resident sufficient - I have the paper work but not an official permit.

I need to go to NL to get my residency permit, and also sell the house I have there and buy another one. House sales seems to be permitted within the UK movement rules,but is that acceptable for international travel - and how do I prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are taking about English Tier 4 restrictions you are probably allowed to leave. Based on https://www.gov.uk/guidance/tier-4-stay-at-home you can leave if you're "returning home"

> If you are visiting the UK and are in a Tier 4 area, you may return home. You should check whether there are any restrictions in place at your destination.

Since you want to become an NL resident this means for you the Netherlands is considered to be the home so you should be allowed to leave

If you are in Scotland's Tier 4 rules are different. You have to adhere to https://www.gov.scot/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-guidance-on-travel-and-transport/#internationaltravel based on it you are only allowed international travel for a couple reasons, going home doesn't seem to be one of them. However selling a  house is:

> travel in connection with moving home (including viewing a property), or for activities in connection with the maintenance, purchase, sale, letting, or rental of residential property that the person owns or is otherwise responsible for.

Comment: Many thanks, you were correct for my tier 4 location in England.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm here in the Netherlands. It was only immigration at Amsterdam who wanted to check why I was trying to enter the country. My papers saying I had been accepted for residency status was OK in lieu of having the actual permit. Others didn't seem to be so lucky and were queuing outside the immigration office.